# extracting data from .net Data.ToBinary()

Tags: .net, datetime, binarywriter

I need to read custom-serialized binary data, written using BinaryWriter class.
To store a date, the original designers used `BinaryWriter.Write( Data.ToBinary() );`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014652/how-do-datetime-tobinary-and-datetime-tofiletime-differ) article sort-of mentions how the ToBinary function works; but what I need, is to build code that will emulate the methods ToBinary() and FromBinary() in other programming languages.

Can anyone look at the following pseudo code and give me an idea of the **real** offset bit counts.

```
long i = DateTime.Now.ToBinary();
// will likely need to add code here to "condition" the value
int yr = (i >> 48) & 0x7fff;
int mo = (i >> 44) & 0xf;
int day = (i >> 36) & 0xff;
int hr = (i >> 28) & 0xff;
int min = (i >> 20) & 0xff;
int sec = (i >> 12) & 0xff;
int ms = i & 0xfff;
```

ps. will this concept even work..or is the date stored in the form of total milliseconds?

Comment: Are you trying to read the serialized data from .net in another language without the framework?

Comment: That is correct. languages including java and objective-C. language conversion is trivial once we know the exact schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any format you want, as long as you do both the serialize & deserialize :) But since a common representation is 'Ticks', why not go with that?
Serialization is all about saving & restoring, as long as you can restore anything you save, serialization worked :)

Comment: thanks, but the Ticks property of a DateTime is read-only. It's too late to choose the format we like; There is a lot of data in the legacy format we need to access anywhere. Additional foresight would have had us build our own date-time serialization format.

Comment: The DateTime constructor can take Ticks as a parameter to instantiate the value... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326681(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Int64** constructor, but you should be careful about the **DateTimeKind** argument. You can get into trouble if you serialize **DateTimeKind.Utc** and deserialize a **DateTimeKind.Unspecified** or **DateTimeKind.Local** value.

**Note:** Probably the safest thing to do is serialize your DateTime values using **ToUniversalTime()** and always construct the return value using **DateTimeKind.Utc**.